# Meteor methods - Internal exception while processing message

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been following the Discover Meteor tutorials in order to create an application that has autopublish and insecure disabled. Things have gone well with autopublish but I haven't been able to successfully display the posts in the collection on the webpage after removing insecure. Could you guys take a look and see what's going on? Thanks.

The tutorials:
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/getting-started-with-meteor/
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-and-security/

The code:

forum.js

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("posts", "published");
  Template.posts.helpers({
    posts: function() {
      Meteor.call("viewPosts","published");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
  Meteor.publish("posts", function(status) {
    return Posts.find({status: status});
  });
  Meteor.methods({
    viewPosts: function(status) {
      return Posts.find({status: status}).fetch(); //This is still problematic
    }
  });
  Posts.allow({
    insert: function() {
      return true;
    }
  })
}
```

forum.html

```
<head>
  <title>Forum</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> posts}}
</body>

<template name="posts">
  <h1>Posts</h1>
  <ul>{{#each posts}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}</ul>
</template>
```

The error message. This appears whether I add or remove .fetch() from the viewPosts method:

=> Meteor server restarted
I20150320-14:27:09.418(0)? Internal exception while processing message { msg: 'method',
I20150320-14:27:09.419(0)?   method: 'viewPosts',
I20150320-14:27:09.419(0)?   params: [ 'published' ],
I20150320-14:27:09.419(0)?   id: '1' } Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from this block in your client code:

```
Template.posts.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    Meteor.call("viewPosts","published");
  }
});
```

The primary way Meteor retrieves data for you on the client is through its publish/subscribe architecture, which you already have in place and looks good. That means that the posts you need to display are already there for you on the client and you don't need to do a `Meteor.call()` to the server to go and get them. Instead, your helper can just look like this:

```
Template.posts.helpers({
  posts: function(){
    return Posts.find({status: "published"});
  }
});
```

Generally, you want to use `Meteor.call()` for responding to template events, e.g. in `Template.posts.events({})`. Server calls generally don't belong in helpers, though I guess there can be exceptions. See this excellent article under 'overworked helpers' for more on that: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the info. I think the mistake was that I thought removing insecure meant handling _everything_ through Meteor.call(). Didn't realize that the publish/subscribe architecture was something that took care of itself.